# JQuery - Replace html button with <li> while keeping values intact

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I have a page with buttons:

```
<input type="button" alue="TEST" 
style="height:40px;width:120px;"
 onClick="javascript:window.location='page.html';" />
```

I want to convert it to (webui):

```
<li><a href="page.html">TEST</a></li>
```

This is the code I have so far: (doesn't seem to work)

```
  $('<input type="button" value=').replaceWith('<li>');
    $('onClick="javascript:window.location=').replaceWith('<a href="');
     $('';" />').replaceWith('" target="_self"></a></li>"');
```

Comment: You can't do that in that way you are doing it.

Comment: Why would you want to send broken HTML to the client and then fix it with jQuery? That's not how things are supposed to work. If you can change the JavaScript of that page, you can also change the HTML right-away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or in a more general way:

```
$("input[type='button']").replaceWith(function() {
   var $button = $(this);
   var $result = $("<a></a>");
   var target = $button.attr("onClick");
   target = target.substr(target.indexOf('\''));
   target = target.substr(0, target.length - 2);
   $result.attr("href", target);
   $result.text($button.val());
   $result = $("<li></li>").append($result);
   return $result;
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ERLgR/1/

Comment: That works but I need it to be dynamic.The value Test will change depending on what buttons are on the page. Is that easy to add to the code?

Comment: Correction! you got it! Thanks Great!!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do string replacement on jQuery objects, that's not how it works. You could do this:

```
$(':button[value="TEST"]').replaceWith($('<li><a href="page.html">TEST</a></li>​​​​'));​
```

Also, as Tomalak added in the comments, the best thing to do would be to change it directly in the HTML, instead of using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a generally bad idea, but here's an answer anyway?

```
var elm = $('input[type="button"]'),
    alue = elm.attr('alue'),
    page = elm.attr('onClick').split("'")[1],
    elm2 = '<li><a href="'+page+'">'+alue+'</a></li>';
elm.replaceWith(elm2)​;​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/7WrjW/)

Comment: That works but I need it to be dynamic.The value Test will change depending on what buttons are on the page. Is that easy to add to the code?

Comment: @user719825 - Just remove the selector match for "alue"! Edited my answer.